How can I use the Scipy Mahalanobis distance implementation for outlier detection?
I have a dataset of different measurements for several individuals in a Pandas dataframe, a similar structure to this random data:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(25, 3), columns=['var1', 'var2', 'var3'])
df.head()

       var1      var2      var3
0 -0.484272 -1.232702 -0.104978
1 -0.104346  0.439150 -0.324739
2 -0.764503  0.679031  1.786502
3 -1.551942  0.136850  0.557289
4  0.081988 -0.482199 -0.560156

I want to figure out if any of these individuals are outliers, and I know that measuring Mahalanobis Distance is a common approach to this problem. I noticed that Scipy also has Mahalanobis function but it takes as input two 1-D arrays and their covariance matrix, rather than an entire dataframe. Is there a way to calculate the MD for each row in a dataframe using the Scipy function?
I found this implementation on Machine Learning Plus which calculates the MD and p-value for each row in a dataframe, and then calculates the p-value from a chi-squared test to determine if the result is an outlier:
df['mahalanobis'] = mahalanobis(df, df[['var1', 'var2', 'var3']])
df['p_value'] = 1 - chi2.cdf(df['mahalanobis'], 2)
df.head()

       var1      var2      var3  mahalanobis   p_value
0 -0.484272 -1.232702 -0.104978     2.972031  0.226272
1 -0.104346  0.439150 -0.324739     0.823351  0.662539
2 -0.764503  0.679031  1.786502     4.490658  0.105893
3 -1.551942  0.136850  0.557289     2.738988  0.254236
4  0.081988 -0.482199 -0.560156     0.386796  0.824154

But I wanted to see if there was a way to just use/modify the Scipy function to accomplish the same thing.

You can implement something along these lines by taking the mean, and comparing each row in your dataset to this mean.
For example:
import scipy
import numpy as np

def mahalanobis_dist_from_center(df):
    cov = df.cov().values
    inv_cov = np.linalg.inv(cov)
    mean = df.mean().values
    scores = []
    values = df.values
    for i in range(values.shape[0]):
        score = scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis(mean, values[i], inv_cov)
        scores.append(score)
    return pd.Series(data=scores, index=df.index)


Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

1 -I think you can achieve that by calculating the covariance matrix of your dataset manually frst.
2 -You need to calculate also the mean of your dataset, as the M. distance measures how far each row is from the mean of the entire dataset.
--For the Mahalanobis Calculation: you need to pass the row's values, the mean of the dataset, and the inverse of the covariance matrix into the mahalanobis function to compute the Mahalanobis distance for each row.
From here you can see the p-value using the chi-squared distribution of each row to determine the outliers I mean if the row is an outlier.
I think we used to do it like this.
